# Java synchronized counter same value is printed by different threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am writing a synchronized counter with Java using a synchronized method. Code is as follows

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

class Counter implements Runnable {
    private static int counter = 0;
    private static final int limit = 1000;
    private static final int threadPoolSize = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < threadPoolSize; i++) {
            executorService.submit(new Counter());
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        incrementCounter();
    }

    private synchronized void incrementCounter() {
        while (counter < limit) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + counter);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

The code is working fine. But at some points, Two threads are printing the same number,

```
pool-1-thread-2 : 29
pool-1-thread-2 : 30
pool-1-thread-1 : 30
pool-1-thread-1 : 32
```

as in the above output, both thread 2 and 1 is printing `30`. I have no idea why this is happening. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Declaring a non-static method as `synchronized` protects from concurrent access to the *same* instance. Two threads can access (at the same time) this method, if they use distinct instances of `Counter`

Comment: @Daniele Thank you for the comment. Using a single instance for all the threads worked. But now it seems like one thread is doing a lot of work and others are starving. Any idea how to share load fairly among all the threads?

Comment: %) the purpose of synchronized is exactly to protect a critical section from concurrent access. So threads block each other as expected. Maybe you can protect a smaller portion of the code (just the bit where threads get-and-increment the counter value); and do some work in parallel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using a `synchronized` method the thread executing the method is getting a lock on the current instance of the `Counter` class so other threads can simultaneously increment the `counter` value without any inhibition.

This is due to the fact that you are creating five different instances of the `Counter` class inside the loop:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < threadPoolSize; i++) {
    executorService.submit(new Counter());
 }
```

So there there can be a moment when five threads can simultaneously execute the `incrementCounter()` method as they are locking on the five different instances of the Counter class (when you use a `synchonized` method you are essentially locking on `this` or the **current class instance**).

You can create a new `static` *lock* object that has to be `synchronized` upon so that all the threads in the pool have and share the same *common* lock object:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

class Counter implements Runnable {
    private static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private static final Object lock = new Object();
    private static final int limit = 1000;
    private static final int threadPoolSize = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < threadPoolSize; i++) {
            executorService.submit(new Counter());
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        incrementCounter();
    }

    private void incrementCounter() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            while (counter.get() < limit) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + counter.get());
                counter.incrementAndGet();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also since this is a situation where you are doing **read-update-write** operation you should consider using an `AtomicInteger` in place of an `int` primitive to make the operation *atomic* that is the operations would happen in a single transaction and other threads can see the latest value always.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It explains why my code is not working. I was thinking that a `synchronized` lock is shared with all the instances. My bad. I used one instance to create all threads and the problem solved (thanks @Daniele for the comment). But it seems like there's a starvation situation going on. Is there any way to share load fairly among threads?